# cej class article not working properly

Tags: errors, article

```
\documentclass[CEJMed,PDF]{cej}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pbsi}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[defn]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[defn]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[defn]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[defn]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[defn]{Example}
\newtheorem{re}[defn]{Result}
 \newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
 \newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
 \newcommand{\newsarrow}{\nearrow \kern-12pt \swarrow \kern-12pt \smallsetminus}
 \newcommand{\nupdownarrow}{\updownarrow \kern-11pt -}
\allowdisplaybreaks


\title{Article title}

\articletype{Research Article} % Research Article, Review Article, Communication, Erratum




\author{Author 1\inst{1,}\email{@gmail.com} and
Author 2\inst{1}
       }

\shortauthor{Author 1 and Author 2}

\institute{\inst{1}
          Affiliation of Authors
                    }

\abstract{In this paper....
}

\keywords{keywords1, keywords2, keywords3, }

\msc{47A63.}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{41}


\section{Introduction}







\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1} C.J.R.Berges, \textit{On metrizability of topological spaces}, Canad. J Math., 20(1978), 795-803.

\bibitem{2} L.Smith, \textit{Linear Algebra: Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics}, Springer Science \& Business Media, (2012).

\bibitem{3} F.Szabo, \textit{Linear Algebra: An Introduction Using Mathematica}, Academic Press, (2000).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

compilation log:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.6.23)  23 JUN 2021 17:48
entering extended mode
**./sample.tex
(sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18> (cej.cls
Document Class: cej 
\cej@tempdimen=\dimen138
\cej@tempcount=\count182
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
 Copyright (c) 2001 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <ogawa@teleport.com>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david@dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 596.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count183
\@tbpen=\count184
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box50
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1610.
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
\c@linecount=\count185
\output=\toks16
\@protection@box=\box51
\@topmark@saved=\toks17
\footins@saved=\box52
\pagesofar=\box53
\footbox=\box54
\pagegrid@col=\count186
Class revtex4 Info: Incorporating package {textcase}  [1998/11/12 v0.06 Text on
ly upper/lower case changing (DPC)]. on input line 3682.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@affil=\count187
\absbox=\box55
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip49
\bibsep=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count196
)
\widetext@top=\box56
\widetext@bot=\box57

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\revsymb.sty
Package: revsymb 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documenta
tion)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 118.
))
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\aps.rtx
File: aps.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentatio
n)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\10pt.rtx
File: 10pt.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentati
on)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count198
\leftroot@=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count266
\DOTSCASE@=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box58
\strutbox@=\box59
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count268
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count269
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count270
\dspbrk@lvl=\count271
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count272
\column@=\count273
\maxfields@=\count274
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks23
\thm@bodyfont=\toks24
\thm@headfont=\toks25
\thm@notefont=\toks26
\thm@headpunct=\toks27
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks28
)
\c@theorem=\count275
\c@lemma=\count276
\c@proposition=\count277
\c@claim=\count278
\c@fact=\count279
\c@corollary=\count280
\c@assumption=\count281
\c@algoritheorem=\count282
\c@remark=\count283
\c@example=\count284
\c@question=\count285
\c@problem=\count286
\c@definition=\count287
\c@axiom=\count288

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks29
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen148
\Gin@req@width=\dimen149
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.
)
Package color Info: Redefining color cej@color on input line 433.
Package color Info: Redefining color abs on input line 434.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys
.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen150
\Hy@linkcounter=\count289
\Hy@pagecounter=\count290

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count291

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Option `final' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count292
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen151

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count293
\Field@Width=\dimen152
\Fld@charsize=\dimen153
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6094.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count294
\c@Item=\count295
\c@Hfootnote=\count296
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver: hpdftex.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count297
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count298

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfileche
ck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecount
er.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip57
) (hypernat.sty
Package: hypernat 2001/07/09 v1.0b hyperref and natbib compatibility (jb)
)
\cej@textwidth=\dimen154
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\layout.sty
Package: layout 2021-03-10 v1.2e Show layout parameters
\oneinch=\count299
\cnt@paperwidth=\count300
\cnt@paperheight=\count301
\cnt@hoffset=\count302
\cnt@voffset=\count303
\cnt@textheight=\count304
\cnt@textwidth=\count305
\cnt@topmargin=\count306
\cnt@oddsidemargin=\count307
\cnt@evensidemargin=\count308
\cnt@headheight=\count309
\cnt@headsep=\count310
\cnt@marginparsep=\count311
\cnt@marginparwidth=\count312
\cnt@marginparpush=\count313
\cnt@footskip=\count314
\fheight=\count315
\ref@top=\count316
\ref@hoffset=\count317
\ref@voffset=\count318
\ref@head=\count319
\ref@body=\count320
\ref@foot=\count321
\ref@margin=\count322
\ref@marginwidth=\count323
\ref@marginpar=\count324
\Interval=\count325
\ExtraYPos=\count326
\PositionX=\count327
\PositionY=\count328
\ArrowLength=\count329
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-06-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-05-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count330
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box60
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2021-06-18 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: lipsum 2021-03-03 v2.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex
File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2021-03-03 v2.3 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks30
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 111.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 113.
))
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/brushscr\pbsi.sty
Package: pbsi 2001/09/17 - BrushScriptX-Italic selection command 'textbsi'


Package pbsi Warning: bad encoding; assuming T1..

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/brushscr\t1pbsi.fd
File: t1pbsi.fd 2001/09/24 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for T1/pbsi.
))
\c@defn=\count331

! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.50 \begin{document}
                     
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.50 \begin{document}
                     
? 
(sample.aux)
\openout1 = `sample.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 50.
Class revtex4 Info: Unrecognized LaTeX tabular. Please update this document cla
ss! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 50.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 50.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 50.
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count332
\scratchdimen=\dimen155
\scratchbox=\box61
\nofMPsegments=\count333
\nofMParguments=\count334
\everyMPshowfont=\toks31
\MPscratchCnt=\count335
\MPscratchDim=\dimen156
\MPnumerator=\count336
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count337
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks32
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 50.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlest
ring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count338
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 50.
 (sample.out) (sample.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `sample.out'.

\cej=\read2
 (sample.cej)
\cej=\write4
\openout4 = `sample.cej'.


Overfull \vbox (833.66574pt too high) detected at line 51
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 51.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 51.


(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
<123.pdf, id=12, 405.03319pt x 405.03319pt>
File: 123.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use 123.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: 123.pdf  used on input line 51.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 72.26999pt x 72.26625pt.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 51--51

 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 51
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbsi/xl/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 13.19997pt on input line 51.
\@rulewidth=\dimen157

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <18> not available
(Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 51.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <18> not available
(Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 51.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <15> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 56.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <15> on input line 56.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <15> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <10.49995> not available
(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <15> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <10.49995> not available
(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <15> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <10.49995> not available
(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 56.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 56.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <11> on input line 64.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 64.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 64.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 64.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+square721exeu on inp
ut line 73.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1square721exeu.fd. on input line 73.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/square721exeu/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 73.

[41{C:/Users/sunantha/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./123.pdf
>] (sample.aux

Package natbib Warning: Citation `1' multiply defined.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `2' multiply defined.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `3' multiply defined.

)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.72pt have occured.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right .


 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11206 strings out of 478838
 161784 string characters out of 2857868
 649962 words of memory out of 3000000
 28968 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 422617 words of font info for 92 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,9n,80p,263b,350s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 <C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\e
crm0700.pk> <C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec
/dpi600\tcrm0800.pk>{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/Us
ers/sunantha/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/brushscr/BrushScriptX-It
alic.pfa><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbsy10.pfb><C
:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmti9.pfb>
Output written on sample.pdf (1 page, 172686 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 114 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 22 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: (1) please explain where one can get the `cej.cls` file as it is not a known class. (2) You should explain what your problem is, cite error messages.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c6vMyvEjEDdBibqjhDWoNI5L5dUsFHSF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Error message (C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/brushscr\t1pbsi.fd))
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.50 \begin{document}

Comment: Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to visit external URLs that require me to login. Please link to an official source for `cej.cls`.

Comment: http://ijmaa.in/file/ijmaa.rar

Comment: article template available at http://ijmaa.in/

Comment: Compiles just fine at my end. Update your miktex (you might need to do that both in miktex user mode and in miktex admin mode). Note that miktex admin mode does not really have anything to do with admin on your Windows syste,

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Then please post the entire log of your compilation of this exact example

Comment: I have added the log file in edit summary

Comment: It should not go into the summary add it to the question after the MWE

Comment: Please update your miktex in miktex user mode and miktex admin mode. `(C:\Users\sunantha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)` my version is version 4.0a 2020

Comment: I tried but not working in windows 7. But working in Windows 10,

Comment: any solution to resolve the issue